# Excel - Match Value and Get Value of Other Column

Tags: excel

I am trying to match 2 values on a table and if match, display the value from other column. Example is as below,

```
A         B          C          D       E                     F
ABC      1          WWE         5       output (1 FROM ABC)   output (10 FROM ABC)
GHI      2          XYY         1
XXY      3          ABC         10
```

May I know how to do it? Can it be done in Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `INDEX/MATCH` formula, for example in column E:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($A1,A:A,0))
```

And in column F:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH($A1,C:C,0))
```

I'd usually wrap these in an `IFERROR(,"")` function to tidy up any errors. These formulas are based on you searching for the value in column A each time, if you want to search for a string instead simply replace `$A1` with "ABC".

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm not in front of my pc now. Will try it later

Comment: **It works great @Jordan**. May I know if I can output it to sheet2?

Comment: The formula would change to something like: `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))` and `=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet1!C:C,0))` - provided the first sheet is named `Sheet1`.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help champion!